# Issue with html to pdf conversion when using itext7

Tags: html, css, fonts, itext7, pdfhtml

Apologies if has been asked before. Pretty new to using Itext. Haven't managed to find the solution to my issue.
I have an html file using 2 non standard font families:

```
p           {font-size:small; font-family:Arial; font-style:normal; margin:0; padding:0 0 15px 0; color:#000000;}
span.header     {font-size:32pt; font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-style:bold; border:0; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 0; color:#000000;}
*****
and more
```

However I haven't been able to get it converted into pdf correctly. The generated pdf file doesn't seem to be picking up 'Comic Sans MS' font at all. Also the layout is distorted (split into 2 pages) with data missing from html. It looks like it's overriding the font sizes and family with Arial throughout.

This is what I have in code:

```
 public static final String FONT1 = "src/main/resources/fonts/Arial.ttf";
 public static final String FONT2 = "src/main/resources/fonts/Arial Bold.ttf";
 public static final String FONT3 = "src/main/resources/fonts/Comic Sans MS.ttf";


 PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
        MediaDeviceDescription mediaDeviceDescription = 
                              MediaDeviceDescription.createDefault();
        mediaDeviceDescription.setOrientation("Portrait");
        properties.setMediaDeviceDescription(mediaDeviceDescription);
        // Passing false three times means not loading standard PDF fonts, fonts shipped with pdfHTML and system fonts
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
        FontProgram fontProgram1 = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT1);
        FontProgram fontProgram2 = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT2);
        FontProgram fontProgram3 = FontProgramFactory.createFont(FONT3);
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram1, "Winansi");
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram2, "Winansi");
        fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram3, "Winansi");
        properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(src), pdf, properties);
```

Can somebody please advise what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. When I remove the 'Arial' fonts support above, then the Comic Sans font seems to be picked up and is applied on the entire html. So, hopefully it is getting recognised. But somehow overshadowed by Arial.

Comment: Actually just tried the suggestion mentioned on the reference link you shared and it seems to have worked! Thanks.

Comment: Now need to explore if I will have to override this in the code instead of having to update all the html files.